# Percent change based on flag column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas data frame:

```
   value   flag
0    1.0   True
1    1.1  False
2    1.2  False
3    1.3  False
4   10.0   True
5   10.1  False
6   10.2  False
7   10.3  False
8   10.4  False
9   10.5  False
```

I want to find the percent change in `value` where `flag` is `False` to the previous `True`. This is the output I'm looking for:

```
   value   flag
0    0.0   True
1   10.0  False
2   20.0  False
3   30.0  False
4    0.0   True
5    1.0  False
6    2.0  False
7    3.0  False
8    4.0  False
9    5.0  False
```

I'm unable to find a good way to do this without looping.

Comment: I do not have time to write a full answer, but this could help you: create a new column, let's say, "result" using .assign(result=lambda d: d['value'].where(d['flag'], pandas.nan). This column contains "value" where "flag" is True. Then, use .ffill() on that column, so that nan are replaced with previous values. This means that "result" contains the first "value" corresponding to "flag == True". Then you can compute your percent change with "result = (value - result) / result" (e.g. using "eval" or "assign").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) by groups created by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) by first value by [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html), so possible divide original values, subtract `1` and multiple `100`:

```
s = df.groupby(df['flag'].cumsum())['value'].transform('first')
df['value'] = df['value'].div(s).sub(1).mul(100)
print (df)
   value   flag
0    0.0   True
1   10.0  False
2   20.0  False
3   30.0  False
4    0.0   True
5    1.0  False
6    2.0  False
7    3.0  False
8    4.0  False
9    5.0  False
```

Performance is better like another solution - `350 times` faster:

```
#10k rows of sample data, best test in real
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)


In [54]: %%timeit
    ...: s = df.groupby(df['flag'].cumsum())['value'].transform('first')
    ...: df['value'] = df['value'].div(s).sub(1).mul(100)
    ...: 
2.93 ms ± 316 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [55]: %%timeit
    ...: df.assign(value=df.groupby(df['flag'].cumsum())['value'].apply(lambda x: x.div(x.iloc[0]).sub(1).mul(100)))
    ...: 
    ...: 
1.03 s ± 110 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to give the right answer?

Answer (score 0):

In one line:

```
>>> df.assign(value=df.groupby(df['flag'].cumsum())['value'].apply(lambda x: x.div(x.iloc[0]).sub(1).mul(100)))
   value   flag
0    0.0   True
1   10.0  False
2   20.0  False
3   30.0  False
4    0.0   True
5    1.0  False
6    2.0  False
7    3.0  False
8    4.0  False
9    5.0  False
>>>
```